# Examine condition of line(s) - touched/untouched

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I need to examine the condition of a line (touched, untouched, traded) to conditionally style them.

I am good with "traded" condition (candle closes above/below line) but got **no idea how to identify the "touched/untouched" condition. (e.g. just a wick into that line)**

Someone please got a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the high and low values to see if a line is touched.

For example, say the line is at 120, high price is 130 and close price is 110.

By looking at those values, you can see that the price pushed through the line and pulled back below it. So, the line was touched.

To check if the line is untouched, simply check if `high < 120`.

Reverse the process for a line below the the price.

Comment: Actually, good idea. Thanks for sharing! Just hard to believe that this another simple need TV got no function for after years in the market.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `line.get_price(LineA, bar_index+1)`.

I have used `ta.cross(close, line.get_price(LineA, bar_index)` and had it work good for me.